# Comparing hashmap key values with an int

Tags: java, hashmap, compare

I'm trying to write an if statement for a game that has default score values for a user. I want to compare the key's value (highscore) to the default score for that user. If score is higher than their highscore, then I will "put" this in the map.

```
 if (map.containsKey(username)) 
 {
    System.out.println("Score for " + username + " is already present");

    if (map.get(highscore) > score) 
    {
      map.put(name, highscore);
    }
 }
```

How do I fix this inner if statement?

Comment: The key to the map is the `username`, right? So what did you expect `get(highscore)` to do? Now think about that and try again, e.g. what's the difference between `score`, `highscore`, and value returned by `get(username)`?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description,I guess the value of map is highscore, the following is the code

```
    if (map.containsKey(username))
    {
        System.out.println("Score for " + username + " is already present");

        if (map.get(username) < score)
        {
            map.put(username, score);
        }
    }
```